# How to observe for changes in the Ember data store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I created this simple JsBin to demonstrate what I'm after.

[JSBIN](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qerogituxi/edit?html,js,output)

I have some Fixture data and each item in it has a boolean property called isFavourite. The `indexRoute` just displays all the available data along with a second section that displays the items that are favourites. Each item also has a class binding to this `isFavourite` property. If it's a favourite, it'll have red text.

There is a second route called `dashboard` which only displays a subset of the data from the store. There is also a button to toggle the favourite property. When this is toggled, the change is reflected in the class binding on the index route but the `Favourites` section, which is just a repeater still shows the old data.

How do I establish a binding for the repeater so that the items change according to the `isFavourite` property?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `this.store.filter`. However, beware this will change in later versions of Ember Data.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the `this.store.find` method I used. Thanks. But how will it help with the binding though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  favourites: function() {
    return this.store.filter('documenter', function(x) {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      return x.get('isFavourite'); 
    });
  }.property('model')
})
```

The reason this works is that `this.store.filter` returns a "live" collection that is updated as things change.

Works for me on your JSBIN.